# Color a DataGrid row based on a DataTable value

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm pulling data from a CSV file, parsing it in a DataTable, and then, setting this DataTable as the ItemsSource of a DataGrid. I'm then looping the DataTable to do some verifications on the data, and I want to color the DataGrid rows accordingly.

The problem is, I can't find the corresponding DataGrid row based on the DataTable row.

Here's my code :

```
Dim dg As New DataGrid
Dim dataTable as DataTable = ParseFile(filePath)
Dim statutList() As String = {"Saisi", "Validé", "Suspendu", "Annulé"}

dg.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView

For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    'This line is what I tried, but it always returns nothing
    Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row)
    If Not statutList.Contains(row("Statut").ToString) Then
        dgrow.Background = Brushes.Red
    End If
Next
```

The problem comes from this line, which doesn't work :

```
Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row)
```

**SOLUTION :**

Both mm8 solutions work. In my case, I used :

```
dg.UpdateLayout()
For Each row As DataRowView In dg.Items.OfType(Of DataRowView)
    Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row)
    If Not statutList.Contains(row("Statut").ToString) Then
        dgrow.Background = Brushes.Red
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct "WPF" way of doing this would be define a RowStyle with one or more data triggers that set the background colour of the row when the "Statut" column of that particular row returns any particular value(s), e.g.:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color" Color="Red" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Statut}" Value="Saisi">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Statut}" Value="Validé">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Statut}" Value="Suspendu">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Statut}" Value="Annulé">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Your current code-behind approach would okay work if you modify it slightly:

```
    For Each row As DataRowView In dg.Items.OfType(Of DataRowView)
        Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row)
        If Not statutList.Contains(row("Statut").ToString) Then
            dgrow.Background = Brushes.Red
        End If
    Next
```

Note that the ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem method won't actually return a DataGridRow container for items that may have been virtualized away if the DataTable contains a lot of rows and you haven't disabled UI virtualization:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">.
```

Obviously disabling the virtualization may lead to performance issues if your DataTable contains a lot of rows.

Also note that need to execute the code once the containers have actually been created, for example when the Loaded event of the window occurs.

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim statutList() As String = {"Saisi", "Validé", "Suspendu", "Annulé"}

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim dg As New DataGrid
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = ParseFile(filePath)

        dg.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView
    End Sub

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        For Each row As DataRowView In dg.Items.OfType(Of DataRowView)
            Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row)
            If Not statutList.Contains(row("Statut").ToString) Then
                dgrow.Background = Brushes.Red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

Comment: I would love to use the wpf approach, but this is just as small part de the data checking code. I have to check some cells against several other values (+200). Your code-behind approach code doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? Are you getting an exception or what happens? You need to execute this code once the containers have actually been created, for example when the Loaded event of the window occurs. You cannot iterate through the containers in the constructor of the window.

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException on the dgrow. The DataGrid is actually loaded before the checking part (the For Each loop comes after the dg.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView which populates the containers)

Comment: No, the visual container are *not* created immediately when you set the ItemsSource property. You must wait until the DataGrid or window has been loaded. I have updated my answer to clarify this. Try to handle the Loaded event of the window as suggested and it should work.

Comment: You are right ! I'm actually a beginner in WPF, and I didn't know that the DataGrid had to be loaded before I could tweak it visually. A `dg.UpdateLayout()` before the for each loop did it for me. I also want to thank you for your code suggestion, although I can't use it, because the data grid can take different csv files structures, and I have to check the data accordingly (which is also why I can't do it in XAML, but if yo uhave any suggestions, just let me know).